# Project ellipsoid with 7 parameter camera

Tags: c++, computer-vision, covariance-matrix

I have a function which projects a point using a 7 parameter camera model:

```c++
Vec2 project(const Rot3& R, // camera orientation
             const Vec3& T, // camera pos
             double f_px,   // focal length
             const Vec3& X) // point in world;
{
    const Vec3 P = R * (X-T);               // Subtract camera position and apply rotation
    const Vec2 p = P.hnormalized() * f_px;  // Normalize and apply focal length
    return p;
}
```

- Rot3 is some convenient representation of a rotation. Assume it is a
  3x3 matrix.
- [Vec3::hnormalized()](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__Geometry__Module.html#title42) returns Vec2(x/z, y/z)

Now I want to extend the function to take an uncertainty estimation of the point I am projecting (a 3x3 covariance matrix - an ellipsoid in world coordinates) and return the 2x2 covariance matrix (an ellipse in pixel coordinates).

I think the reference to Hartley & Zisserman’s *Multiple View Geometry In Computer Vision* [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2757064/350530) applies, but I can't figure out the math of it.

Comment: Can't you project the eigenvectors that represent your uncertainty-ellipsoid the same way you project the point `X`? I don't know if that's going to give you an ellipse. Don't remember the math very well, so I could be wrong.